# undefined method `category_path' in creating form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

im creating my first FORM in rails and i want be able to edit my categories which are in db.
**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <% if @category.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@category.errors.count, "error") %> brání v uložení kategorie.</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @category.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @category %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', backend_categories_path %>
```

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:3000/backend/categories/1/edit
```

**Error:**

```
undefined method `category_path' for #<#<Class:0x46696f8>:0x3f38478>
```

**Routes:**

```
    home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                  home#index
                 root        /                                      home#index
              contact        /contact(.:format)                     home#contact
         backend_root        /backend(.:format)                     backend/admin#index
   backend_categories GET    /backend/categories(.:format)          backend/categories#index
                      POST   /backend/categories(.:format)          backend/categories#create
 new_backend_category GET    /backend/categories/new(.:format)      backend/categories#new
edit_backend_category GET    /backend/categories/:id/edit(.:format) backend/categories#edit
     backend_category GET    /backend/categories/:id(.:format)      backend/categories#show
                      PUT    /backend/categories/:id(.:format)      backend/categories#update
                      DELETE /backend/categories/:id(.:format)      backend/categories#destroy
```

I also have new form which is rendering ok
**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @category, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => {:class => "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "Vytvořit" %>
<% end %>
```

So i have a question why edit form isnt working and what is benefit of having form in separate file ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the `/backend/` portion of the route; try this:

```
<%= form_for [:backend, @category] do |f| %>
```